# WireGuard handshake doesn't adhere to routing table

Tags: networking, macos, routing, wireguard, cisco-anyconnect

I am trying to chain a WireGuard tunnel after a Cisco AnyConnect VPN into my company network. In the office, I can activate the tunnel and everything works perfectly. At home, I first activate the AnyConnect VPN.

Running `route -n get <ENDPOINT IP>` returns the AnyConnect gateway and interface. Furthermore, `traceroute <ENDPOINT IP>` also gives the expected result. However, `tcpdump -host <ENDPOINT IP>` shows that when trying to activate the WireGuard tunnel, the UDP packet is sent through the default interface (WiFi) and never reaches the server.

I have tried using the AnyConnect VPN for all traffic, not just on company networks. Then, the handshake works, because the AnyConnect interface shows up first in the routing table. But in this case, I cannot use the tunnel as traffic going to the tunnel IP range is still routed through the AnyConnect VPN. Adding new routes via `route -n add -net 10.60.0.0 <WG GATEWAY>` does not cause an error, but the rule is not actually present in the routing table afterward.

*Important:* The 10.60.0.0/16 network is not used by the company, so adding the route above does not conflict with already present routes.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to tell WireGuard explicitly which interface to use for the handshake?
2. How can I exclude certain IPs from Cisco AnyConnect?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: It's on a macOS system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the CLI for setting up the WireGuard interface. With exactly identical settings and both being created while the VPN was off, using `wg-quick up <name>.conf` worked, but the app didn't.

Very interesting behavior, might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The WireGuard article
[Routing & Network Namespace Integration](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/)
may have the explanation:

> When a WireGuard interface is created (with ip link add wg0 type
> wireguard), it remembers the namespace in which it was created. "I was
> created in namespace A." Later, WireGuard can be moved to new
> namespaces ("I'm moving to namespace B."), but it will still remember
> that it originated in namespace A.
>
> WireGuard uses a UDP socket for actually sending and receiving
> encrypted packets. This socket always lives in namespace A – the
> original birthplace namespace. This allows for some very cool
> properties. Namely, you can create the WireGuard interface in one
> namespace (A), move it to another (B), and have cleartext packets sent
> from namespace B get sent encrypted through a UDP socket in namespace
> A.

As you created the interface in the office, WireGuard now uses the same
interface as used in the office.

To make it use the VPN, the solution might be to recreate the
WireGuard interface while the VPN is connected.

Comment: Ah, I remember reading that page as well but I didn't understand it fully at the time. However, this did not solve the problem, unfortunately. Same issue.